# App using webview, open all external links in external app or browser

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, hyperlink

I'm trying to create an app by loading my website through webview (Kotlin). To this point it works.

What I'm trying to find out is how to open all external links listed on my website (absolute URL's) with the default browser or app. The external links are websites but also twitter posts.

I read following articles, but without success:

- [WebView link click open default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229494/webview-link-click-open-default-browser)
- [Open link in browser instead of default app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494806/open-link-in-browser-instead-of-default-app)
- [Open multiple links in external browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211857/open-multiple-links-in-external-browser)
- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links